# What's the difference between a HP P420i (2GB FBWC) and a HP p822 (2GB FBWC) Raid

Tags: raid, hp-proliant, raid-controller

I am looking to buy a HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8 2U 12x 3.5 (LFF) server and one of the configuration options I am being offered is whether it comes with an HP P420i or a HP p822 Raid Controller.

However, from looking at the documentation on both of these controllers https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03348189 (for the 420) and https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03383547 (for the HP P822), I'm struggling to understand what the difference is between the two.

Also one other point is that I would also be looking to install some WD Red Drives into the ProLiant Server (with the largest being 6TB). Would either of these Raid Controllers not be compatible with the Red Drives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main user-visible difference is that the P420i is a classical internal controller, to be used with a local backplane, while the P822 has four *external* SAS connector. You need to use a P822 when using disaggregated computing and storage - ie: when connecting your head node to one or more external JBOD chassis.